# Create STAC catalog file for my s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, open-data-cube, amazon-s3, stac

I have s3 private bucket which contains .tif files.
Now, I need to create STAC file like the following:

- https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v0
- https://earthengine-stac.storage.googleapis.com/catalog/catalog.json
- https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/stac-server/

My goal is to index file (in Open Data Cube) with the `stac-to-dc` method.

How can I create this .json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. The easiest way to do this is using [RIO STAC](https://github.com/developmentseed/rio-stac), which was developed by the magnificent Vincent Sarago. I use it programmatically (from Python).

Make sure you enable the Projection extension, but other than that, that's all you need to do.

[Here's some code that does it.](https://github.com/digitalearthafrica/deafrica-scripts/blob/main/deafrica/data/chirps.py#L118)

And example is this:

```py
    item = create_stac_item(
        path_to_tif_file,
        id="this-can-be-any-string",
        with_proj=True,
        input_datetime=datetime(2021, 12, 25),
        properties={
            "odc:product": "not_required_but_useful_for_odc"
        },
    )
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! I will try!